# React - What's the best practice to refresh a list of data after adding a new element there?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a simple todo list. I have a form for adding a new todo list item and under it are listed all items in the todo list. When I add a new item through a form, I want to refresh the list of existing todo list items.

Items.jsx:

```
class Items extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
            loading: true
       };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/v1/items')
            .then(response => {
            this.setState({ items: response.data, loading: false });
        });
        console.log('state.items: '+this.state.items);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        axios.get('/api/v1/items')
            .then(response => {
            this.setState({ items: response.data, loading: false });
        });
        console.log('componentDidUpdate: '+this.state.items);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ItemSE.Group>
            {
                this.state.items.map(item => {
                    return <Item key={item.id} data={item} />
                })
            }
            </ItemSE.Group>
        );
    }
}

export default Items
```

App.jsx:

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
          item_msg: ''
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log(this.state.item_msg);  
        axios.post('/api/v1/items', {
            item: this.state.item_msg
          })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
    }

    handleInputChange(e) {
        this.setState({ item_msg: e.target.value });
        console.log('item_msg: '+this.state.item_msg);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <MainHeaderr />
                <Container>
                    <NewItemForm 
                        send_form={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} 
                        onInputChange={this.handleInputChange} 
                        typed={this.state.item_msg} />
                    <Items />
                </Container>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I added `componentDidUpdate` to the `Items.jsx` file - when I add a new todo list, this new todo will indeed display immediately to the list - that's cool. However, I don't really feel this is the best practice.
When I look to the JS console, I see there hundreds of `componentDidUpdate:`.

Thus, what's the best way to refresh a list to todos?

Comment: you shouldn't be using componentDidUpdate without a conditional check, otherwise it will lead to an infinite cycle or re-render and API calls because of setState in componentDidUpdate

Comment: you can store `items` in `App` component, then pass it into props of `Items` component - This approach is ugly a little bit, so many people are using Redux/Relay to store global data

Comment: Can't you just add the new item to the list instead of fetching the full list ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is one of the most challenging part for the newcomers into `ReactJS`. 
You should not make stateful components at the every level.

Choose a common owner for the state. In your case `Items` component can't change it's state by itself without data from the parent `App` component, so there are no reasons to keep the state in this place.

Basically, you should keep `items` array and `isLoading` flag in the `App` component and then simply pass it into the `Items` as a prop.

Then, you may update your list by re-fetching data after adding new item on the backend or just add it into the list.

Also, you should update parent's `App` state on every input changes.

There are two ways:

1. You can keep it in `NewItemForm` state and then pass onSubmit into the parent event handler as a function prop.
2. Just make it uncontrollable and don't keep it in state at all and parent will take this param from `event.target.value`. (As it is now).

In both cases it won't re-render your list every time. 
Because of this you should omit the `handleInputChange` from `App` component.

For example:
**App.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Initial state
    this.state = {
        items: [],
        isLoading: false,
    }

}

handleSubmit(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    const { value } = e.target;        

    this.setState({ isLoading: true });

    axios.post('/api/v1/items', {
        item: value
      })
      .then(response => {
        // there are several ways - choose ONE of them

        // 1. If server returns you the created item
        // you can just add this item into the list
        this.setState(prevState => {
               return {
                   items: [...prevState.items, response.data],
                   isLoading: false,
               }
        });

        // 2. But if there are any users who can make changing simultaneously with you 
        // (if not - just imagine it :) ) - it's better to make re-fetch data from server
        axios.get('/api/v1/items')
            .then(response => {
                this.setState(prevState => ({ items: response.data, isLoading: false }); 
            })
            .catch(err => { console.log('Something bad is happened:', err) });
}
```

Finally, just pass data it into your `Items` component.

```
render() {
    const { items, isLoading } = this.state;

    return (
      ...
      <Items items={items} isLoading={isLoading} />
      ...
    )
}
```

I advice you to read this article if you haven't read it yet - https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article, a very good read.