# Can my React component listen to changes in the server and update itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a React component that renders a list of items. I have a different component which allows user to add a new item.  This new item is created by making an async call to the server. Can the component that renders the list listen to changes in the server and update itself.

The new item is added through a modal hence when the modal is closed, an action needs to be triggered to update the component that renders the list of items. Right now I am having to refresh the browser to reflect the changes in the UI.

If I close my modal, there is no way I am triggering a change to the component that renders the list of items. I thought about adding the result of the async call which is a list item to the state using redux as a way to cause a re-render. However, the client I am interfacing with does not give back all the properties that the items requires (as a part of the Typescript interface). Hence this method won't work. An alternate way to force a re-render to the component that displays the list. But again, can't really think of a way that would be work and how would I trigger the componentDidUpdate hook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - What's the best practice to refresh a list of data after adding a new element there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49378949/react-whats-the-best-practice-to-refresh-a-list-of-data-after-adding-a-new-el)

Comment: If the async call gets the changed things in its response, it can then update the Redux state, after which the other component should update.

Comment: Yes @RemcoGerlich. That was the exact worklow I had in mind. But the returned item from the async call is in the Collection + JSON Hypermedia format and is missing some of the properties as compared to the original item returned by the server. Also, if I add the returned item to the list using a new action, am I violating the single source of truth pattern? Just thinking out loud. To make this workflow work, I am having too manipulate the data models in Typescript, creating type errors throughout the codebase.

Comment: That's a whole list of things (about the missing properties, the new action, the data models in typescript) that raise eyebrows and that really should be in your question as code so we can say something useful about them. It's just the normal way.

Answer (score 5):

if (the server supports [webSockets](https://javascript.info/websocket)) {

use [webSockets](https://javascript.info/websocket);

} else {

use [socket.io](https://socket.io/);

}